# error while running the libor masek code for iris recognition

Tags: matlab, iris-recognition

When I run the libor masek code for Iris Recognition, I am calling the segmentiris function, i get the error message as

```
??? Undefined function or method 'conv2' for input arguments of type 'double' and   attributes 'full 3d
real'.

Error in ==> filter2 at 73
    y = conv2(hcol, hrow, x, shape);

Error in ==> canny at 40
im = filter2(gaussian,im);        % Smoothed image.

Error in ==> findcircle at 43
[I2 or] = canny(image, sigma, scaling, vert, horz);

Error in ==> segmentiris at 49
[row, col, r] = findcircle(eyeimage, lirisradius, uirisradius, scaling, 2, 0.20, 0.19, 1.00, 0.00);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter each colour (RGB) separately in 2D:

```
filter_g = zeros(size(im_double));

for i = 1:3
  filter_g(:,:,i) = conv2(gauss, im_double(:,:,i);
end
```

Or you can just use `convn()`